# How to keep a number below n

Tags: python, math, formatting

I have a python program that outputs a list of coordinates that correspond to points in a survey. To keep this simple, I'm trying to make any coordinate above n (36) display something like: `1.8+36`, which is 37.8, however `1x1.8` (same number) could also work, or any similar permutation... the coordinates are in lists (one for x and one for y). I currently use an if statement, but that obviously only works for numbers less than 72.

Comment: please list your code. Nothing is "obvious" unless we can see it...

Comment: Why 36? Does it have some special meaning to surveyors? How is `1.8+36` simpler than `37.8`? And how does 1 * 1.8 equal 37.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your values remain below 1296 (36*36), you can divide your number by 36 and represent it as this number into 36.

```
input_1 = 105
output_1 = (105 * 1.0) / 36 # 2.197

print '36*' + output_1 # 36*2.197
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was writing up as you posted it, lol. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to use integer division and the modulus operator (which takes the remainder), so;

```
blocks = n // 36
small = n % 36
format_n = str(small) + ' + ' + str(blocks) + '*36'
```

Should give i + k*36, where i < 36 and k is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = float(input())

if n > 36:
    result = str(n -36) + "+36"
else:
    result = n

print(result)
```

this outputs the remainder of n-36, and then +36, for example if n is 124.79, 88.79+36 is outputted.

Comment: it does exactly what you asked, your question was unclear if this wasn't what you were asking for